# Identificar número telefone

Tags: c#

Preciso de um código C# que identifica chamadas do telefone. Exemplo: tipo bina. Não sei que tipo de aparelho terei que utilizar.

Dei uma pesquisada, parece que tem até em USB, mas não tenho noção como conectar com a porta e fazer a comunicação com a mesma. Preciso pegar o número do telefone e colocar na aplicação, no caso pode ser quando o telefone tocar.

Comment: Não tem como te dar uma resposta, cada aparelho funciona de uma forma diferente

Comment: Dificil te ajudar se você não sabe que tipo de aparelho será utilizado.

Comment: Estarei utilizando o IC BOX

Comment: Pq fecharam? É pra rodar em pc? Independe de aparelho, você precisa se comunicar com o modem, e consegue sim fazer isso. Você fica "escutando" o modem e quando o telefone toca, você consegue saber o número de quem está ligando, caso esteja disponível. Fiz isso já, há muitos anos atrás com VB6... Não deveriam ter fechado a pergunta. Se não entenderam, solicitem esclarecimentos.